# Should we add a "this site is not affiliated to Stack Overflow.." disclaimer to our website app?

Tags: discussion, support

I've checked legal section but it does not say anything specific of this aspect apart from:

**Do feel free to explain that your product is built on the Stack Exchange platform so people understand your product.**

I saw a couple of apps that already have a disclaimer (Stackathlon, Saggregator):

> API Site names and logos
>   (stackoverflow.com, serverfault.com,
>   superuser.com, stackapps.com,
>   meta.stackoverflow.com) are © Stack
>   Overflow Inc. This site is in no way
>   affiliated with Stack Overflow Inc.
>   except for the fact that we use their
>   awesome API to provide you this
>   service.

and

> This site is not affiliated with Stack
>   Exchange, Stack Overflow or any of
>   their family of sites. The data used
>   to produce this page is covered under
>   a Creative Commons license.

Do you have any guidelines to follow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just be reasonable. Trademark law is based on the principle of not confusing "the reasonable person" as to the origin of goods and services.

Comment: ahhh... a clear and calm voice of reason.