# Copying CSS from stackoverflow for use in an app?

Tags: support, legal

Is it ok / legal / allowed to copy some of the styles from stackoverflow / serverfault / etc. for use in a stack app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look to [Trademark guidance](https://stackapps.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

> Design of Your Product
>
> - Do not copy the look and feel of our products.

and quoting Joel answering a [previous question](https://stackapps.com/questions/898/should-we-add-a-this-site-is-not-affiliated-to-stack-overflow-disclaimer-to-o):

> Just be reasonable. Trademark law is
>   based on the principle of not
>   confusing "the reasonable person" as
>   to the origin of goods and services.

So, i don't think it is a good idea to copy StackOverflow's CSS for your apps.

Comment: I assume something like StackTack falls under the "reasonable person" argument?  Or StackTack is fine since they are just pulling data verbatim? http://stackapps.com/questions/518/stacktack-a-javascript-widget-you-can-stick-anywhere

Comment: @mlaw - you should use the '@' notation in a comment (like Kevin and I did) to ensure that an addressed commenter get's notified about your follow up question (e.g. you seem to be asking @Kevin here specifically ;) - otherwise only the original posters of answers/questions (e.g. systempuntoout here) will get this notification.

Comment: @Steffen thanks.  Since I can't edit a comment, I guess I'll have to re-post that one for Kevin to get the notification?

Comment: @Kevin please see the second comment.

Comment: @mlaw - StackTack doesn't copy our L&F verbatim, and also can be distinguished from SO by a reasonable person.